# Show all the error inline in Emacs lsp-mode

Tags: flycheck, lsp-mode, lsp, lsp-ui

I am an Emacs newbie transitioning from Neovim.
In Neovim's built-in LSP client, I am able to see all the errors inline.
Please notice how every error is displayed on the problematic line immediately at the end of the line.
Here is a screenshot:
[image]

And now here is how it looks in Emacs:
[image]
Please notice that:

1. Only one error is visible, where the cursor is currently on.
2. By default, the error shown on the right side of the screen instead of immediately at the end of the line like in Vim.
3. The error is shown also below the line, in addition to the right side of the screen. This was achieved by this: https://github.com/flycheck/flycheck-inline.

How can I make Emacs behave like Neovim?